# If X is a substitute, how do you call what is being substituted?

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's say we have an event: *X is substituted with Y.*
To describe this event, I can refer to Y as the 'substitute'. Is there any term for 'X'?

I tried my best answering this on my own, but googling this question turns out to be hard.

Comment: Depending on context, original, notional, nominal, planned, billed, expected, genuine, real

Comment: Can these be used as nouns though? As in "The substitute replaces the original."? This sounds odd to me.

Comment: *The substitute replaces the original.* - there is nothing wrong with this. Compare to: *The red replaces the blue.*

Comment: In general, it is vastly preferable to use FOR instead of WITH, with the general structure of "substitute (new-thing) for (old-thing)."  [Here](http://www.writing-skills.com/60-second-fix-substitute-for-or-with) is a page discussing it, and there are many questions here on ELU that deal with *substitute* as well.

Answer (score -2):

I think Replacee would be correct answer for this.

Comment: @NigelJ Normally true, but I think this word is kind of easily understood. https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/replacee I'm not saying it's a "correct answer", though.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage! We're looking for long answers that provide some [explanation and context](//english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Please explain why your answer is right, ideally with [citations](//english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing). Answers that don't include explanations may be [removed](//english.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).